# How many requests can Puma buffer simultaneously?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, file-upload, webserver, puma

I understand a benefit of Puma over other Rails web servers is how it handles slow clients. While a Puma server receives and downloads a (potentially slow) request, it can still receive and download other requests that might download quicker and be passed on to a worker for processing before the slow request has finished being received.

But I can't find any information about what, if any, limits there are to this.

**Can Puma download any number of requests at the same time? If 1000 slow requests hit it at the same time, would the 1001st request reach a Puma worker first assuming it wasn't a slow request?**

I guess what I'm interested in generally is what impact multiple slow requests have on other requests, including each other - because I'm working on an application that's likely to involve plenty of 'slow requests' (image uploads from phones via 3G).

[This great article](https://www.speedshop.co/2015/07/29/scaling-ruby-apps-to-1000-rpm.html) by @nate-berkopec helps explain in principle how Puma helps with slow clients: "In clustered mode, then, Puma can deal with slow requests (thanks to a separate master process whose responsibility it is to download requests and pass them on)..." Any more light anyone can shed would be very welcome.

Comment: Not an answer, but you may get value from https://www.rubyraptor.org/how-we-made-raptor-up-to-4x-faster-than-unicorn-and-up-to-2x-faster-than-puma-torquebox/#slow_client_problem

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of considerations, such as the IO polling system, memory and concurrency concerns.

#### IO polling system

**Edit (Sep. 9th, 2020)**: By now the Puma server is running on the `nio4r` and should no longer be subject to the limits of the `select` system call (where file descriptor values are limited to 1023).

As far as I know, Puma uses the `select` system call (unlike iodine or passenger, which also protect you from slow clients but use `kqueue` or `epoll`).

The `select` system call is limited on most systems (usually up to 1024 clients / `maxfd`). I would assume that would create a limit.

However, I know Puma is working on replacing the `select` system call with something both portable and effective (such as leveraging the `nio4r` gem).

I don't know if that was already achieved, but it will break this limit and probably improve performance.

#### Memory

Slow clients still consume memory as they slowly fill the buffer with their header data or slowly download the buffered data that was sent (keeping the buffer in the memory until the download is complete).

Memory limitations will always add limitations to slow client handling.

Some limitations can be elevated, such as sending static files using X-Sendfile (supported with iodine, and when Puma or passenger are running under nginx)... but this isn't really something you can fix.

#### Concurrency

Puma handles slow clients within the Ruby's GIL (global instruction lock). This means that no other threads / instructions can execute while Puma is handling slow clients.

This is often a non issue, but a large enough number of slow clients increases the cost of context switching and system calls. This could (potentially) slow a server considerably.

Both Passenger and iodine perform slow client buffering outside of the GIL, allowing these system calls to be truly concurrent (when multiple CPU cores are available).

This will mitigate the issue but not fully solve the issue.

#### Conclusion and Caveats

The biggest issue is usually the IO polling system. A solution for this is on Puma's roadmap (maybe already implemented, I'm not sure).

The other issues (memory limits and concurrency limits) are relatively less important, but they can't be mitigated without using language extensions (the iodine server is written in C and Passenger is written in C++).

Since Puma doesn't (currently) require any language extensions (except for it's integrated HTTP parsers in C and Java), these issue remain.

I should point out that I'm the author for the iodine HTTP/Websocket server, so I'm somewhat biased.